# Ktor interceptor response.bodyAsText consumes the response body

Tags: android, ktor

I'm using ktor for my new app, and I'm running into an issure where I want to log the response body, but in doing so throws an error because the response JSON is no longer available for deserializing.

Here is my client (notice that I already have logging installed, but for some reason that doesn't work, so I resorted to logging in an interceptor -- Fix this too, KTOR...)

```
val client = HttpClient {
        install(ContentNegotiation) {
            json(json)
        }
        install(Logging) {
            logger = Logger.DEFAULT
            level = LogLevel.ALL
        }
        defaultRequest {
            url(BuildConfig.HOST_NAME)
            contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
            accept(ContentType.Application.Json)
        }
    }.apply {
        plugin(HttpSend).intercept { req ->
            val call = execute(req)
            val response = call.response
            println("responseBody=${response.bodyAsText()}")
            call
        }
    }
```

And the error I get

```
io.ktor.serialization.JsonConvertException: Illegal input
Caused by: kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonDecodingException: Expected start of the object '{', but had 'EOF' instead at path: $
```

The JSON serializer is basically receving an EOF -- lol.

If I REMOVE the `println("responseBody=${response.bodyAsText()}")`, the app works fine.

If I try this

```
println("responseBody=${response.body<Any>()}")
```

the printed output is this

```
body=HttpResponse[http://localhost:3000/myApp/request, 200 OK]
```

Which is obviously unusable

Comment: The `Logging` plugin logs a response body with the following code: `client.get("https://httpbin.org/get")`. Unfortunately, receiving body in the `HttpSend` plugin causes its consumption so you get the `JsonDecodingException`. Here is a related issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-4225.